# Скорость Collections.sort() и TreeMap / TreeSet

Tags: java, сортировка

Поиск элемента по значению из `TreeMap` и `TreeSet` занимает `O(logN)`.
В спецификации на `Collections.sort()` сказано, что в этом случае идет обращение к `Arrays.sort()` и получается `O(N logN)`.

Вопрос: почему?

Я правильно понимаю, что причина в реализации `TreeMap` в виде черно-красного дерева, а сортированных коллекций - в виде обычного массива? Если да, то почему разница такая большая? Получается, что для поиска элемента по значению делается перебор всех элементов по порядку и сортировка всего лишь уменьшает возможное время на обработку каждого сравнения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Collections.sort` принимает аргументом только коллекции, реализующие интерфейс `List`:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

Поиск элемента и в красно-черном дереве и в отсортированном массиве можно осуществлять за O(logN), при условии что поиск в массиве будет происходить не методом `indexOf`, а бинарным поиском, с помощью `Collections.binarySearch`

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то ответ таков: вы правы. TreeMap — это красно-черное дерево, а в `Collections.sort()` используется другой алгоритм — merge sort. В `Arrays.sort()` используется quicksort.